# Azure Stream analytics unique event tag

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

So I think I've been miss understanding the eventID meta property. I've been processing it as a PK constraint into SQL. However, if I want to back fill my database with a custom start time in the past, I'm getting the same data being input?

Comment: I think it's off-topic question, please provide more details about your situation. What have you tried?Any unusual result have you seen?

Comment: The goal of eventID is to have a consistent ID for the same message. So event if the message is reprocessed another time you will have the same ID. Then, because we don't do upsert for SQLDB, that means you may receive several entries with the same eventID, so it may not be used for PK directly but more for a dedup logic.

Comment: @JSAzure thanks that were my thoughts. I realize I've misunderstood the original documentation.